# How to write "Magic Number" boot block to the first sector of my flash drive

Tags: linux, boot, dd, embedded, boot-loader

I want to try and see how the BIOS detects boot device using the magic number (`0xaa55`) by writing

```
e9 fd ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa
```

to the first sector of my pendrive as said in the experiment in the book ["Writing a Simple Operating System — from Scratch"](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eexr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) (pg-4).

Can this be achieved by using `dd` command alone? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I would use `printf` to produce the raw bytes and redirect it to `dd` for writing to the device.

You need to know the device name of your pendrive, but if it were `/dev/sdf` for example you could accomplish this in 3 steps.

**Make sure you use the correct device name for your pendrive!**

1. Zero out the first 512 byte sector:

```
printf '\x00%.0s' {1..512} | sudo dd of=/dev/sdf
```

2. Write the first 3 bytes to the start of the sector:

```
printf '\xe9\xfd\xff' | sudo dd of=/dev/sdf
```

3. Write the last 2 bytes to the end of the sector:

```
printf '\x55\xaa' | sudo dd seek=510 oflag=seek_bytes of=/dev/sdf
```

Comment: You don't technically have to zero the sector first. Just use `conv=sync` with dd to pad with NUL to the block size.

Comment: @CR. wouldn't that zero the entire device and not just the first 512 bytes?

Comment: No, sync only pads the input data to the size of a block.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I tried the above method, but while booting, my PC doesn't seem to recognize my flash drive as a boot media, it directly boots to grub menu
Also, why do we have to zero out the first 512 bytes?

Comment: @user13675319 The boot issue is a separate question. The reason for zeroing out the first 512 bytes is the example you give (and link to) shows a 512 byte block that is all zeroes between the `e9 fd ff` and `55 aa`.